# Ошибка 401 при парсинге

Tags: python, парсер

На сайте нужно производить авторизацию, я ее делаю, но потом нужно отправить запрос с данными чтобы получить ответ с данными, при попытке отправить, получаю ошибку 401

Вот моя попытка это сделать:

```
url = "https://affiliates.pinnacle.com/v2/local-login-partner.asp"
payload = {
    "userName": "",
    "password": "",
}
session = requests.Session()
user = fake_useragent.UserAgent().random
header = {
    "user-agent": user
}
json_data = {
    'skip': 0,
    'take': 10,
    'allowServerColumns': True,
    'filters': [],
    'parameters': [
        {
            'fieldName': 'StartDate',
            'operator': '=',
            'value': '2023-09-01T00:00:00.000Z',
        },
        {
            'fieldName': 'EndDate',
            'operator': '=',
            'value': '2023-09-06T00:00:00.000Z',
        },
        {
            'fieldName': 'MerchantId',
            'operator': '=',
            'value': '0',
        },
        {
            'fieldName': 'BannerId',
            'operator': '=',
            'value': '0',
        },
        {
            'fieldName': 'ReportName',
            'operator': '=',
            'value': 'Accounts Report - simple',
        },
    ],
    'sort': [],
    'groupBy': '',
}


response = session.post(url, json=payload, headers=header)
# Ваш предыдущий код для аутентификации
cookie_dict = [{"domain": key.domain, "name": key.name, "path": key.path, "value": key.value} for key in session.cookies]

session2 = requests.Session()

for cookies in cookie_dict:
    session2.cookies.set(**cookies)

rr = session2.post('https://affiliates.pinnacle.com/netapp/api/ReportService/RunReport', json=json_data, headers=header)
print(rr)

if rr.status_code == 200:
    # Здесь можно получить данные после успешного запроса
    print(rr.json())
    profile = 'https://affiliates.pinnacle.com/members/welcome.asp?language='
    profile_respone = session.get(profile).text

else:
    print("Не удалось получить данные")
```

Comment: 1) А зачем вы создаёте две отдельные сессии? 2) А вы проверяете, что авторизация вообще выполнилась успешно?

Comment: @andreymal авторизация проходит успешно, вторая сессия чтобы использовать куки входа первой сессии

Comment: 1) А как вы проверяете, что авторизация проходит успешно? 2) Что вам помешало использовать одну только первую сессию со всеми куками внутри неё?

Comment: @andreymal авторизацию я проверял обычной проверкой, сейчас ее нет, но авторизация нормально проходит, насчет одной сессии, я тоже пробовал, либо неправильно, либо я хз